# why use int[2] array when creating a pipe?

Tags: c, linux

```
int channel[2];
pipe(channel);
```

I am beginner of c programming and I saw this code to use to communicate between two different process.why pass int[2] array as argument and what we use it in pipe ?

Can we pass any size of array to pipe ? (eg. int channel[5])

Comment: You _can_ pass a longer array but only the first two elements will be filled in by `pipe()`.

Comment: If you mean: `int fd[6]; pipe(fd); pipe(fd+2); pipe(fd+4);` or something similar, certainly you can do that. They're all just addresses where *at least* two contiguous `int` reside.

Comment: (Remember that arrays decay to pointers. The `pipe` function only cares about the objects at ptr+0 and ptr+1, or the first two array elements.)

Comment: A question about the semantics of a library function is best answered by reading the documentation: http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two FDs correspond with the two sides of a pipe. By its nature, a pipeline has an input end and an output end -- more than that doesn't make sense.

If you pass in anything larger than an `int[2]`, the other slots will be unused.

Comment: And passing something smaller than 2 `int`-s is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)